# Where is the command `gnome-display-properties`

Tags: command-line, gnome

After upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to 13.10, the command `gnome-display-properties` is gone. I can open it via `gnome-control-center`.

How can I open this dialogue just with a command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use:

```
gnome-control-center display
```

See `man gnome-control-center` for more info.